# Using PowerShell to get a file name in a directory

Tags: powershell

I have a directory that contains a file called Bruce.txt. I need to copy the file name to a flat file. I tried using the `copy-item` command but that copies the contents not the name.

Is there a command to copy Bruce.txt (the name not the contents) to a flat file? So after it completes there will be a file called process.txt and its contents will be Bruce.txt.  I tried using

`Copy-Item -Path "C:\Users\Bruce\deploy\*.txt" -Destination "C:\Users\Bruce\process.txt"`.

Inside of deploy is a text file called Bruce.txt with the contents of `select count() from EMP_NR`.

I need Bruce.txt the name copied to process.txt not the Select count() etc.

For Shell script I use the ls command and it works wonderful what can I use for Powershell?

Answer (score 13):

You need to use the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet.

```powershell
Get-ChildItem C:\Users\Bruce\deploy\*.txt | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | Out-File C:\Users\Bruce\process.txt -Force -Append
```

However, as you're using PowerShell, `ls` would actually work for you here, as would `gci` and `dir` as they're all aliases for `Get-ChildItem`:

```powershell
>  get-alias | ? {$_.DisplayName -ilike "*get-childitem*" }

CommandType     Name
-----------     ----
Alias           dir -> Get-ChildItem
Alias           gci -> Get-ChildItem
Alias           ls -> Get-ChildItem
```

You can also use `>` or `>>` instead of piping to `Out-File` if you so wish.

Because the `Get-Childitem` cmdlet returns a list of objects, you then need to also select which information you want to extract from the object. If you do a `ls` in a directory with some content, you will see the contents are formatted into a table.

By using the `Select-Object` cmdlet, you can extract the object properties you want to write to your file, in this case the `Name` property.

Comment: eg `get-alias -d get-childitem` works these days to get aliases from full cmdlet names. For completeness, we omit the `-d` when getting the cmdlet name from an alias: `get-alias ls`.