# using for-loop in azure pipeline jobs

Tags: for-loop, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm gonna use a for-loop which scans the files (value-f1.yaml, values-f2.yaml,...) in a folder and each time use a filename as a varibale and run the job in Azure pipeline job to deploy the helmchart based on that values file. The folder is located in the GitHub repository. So I'm thinking of something like this:

pipeline.yaml

```
 stages:
  - stage: Deploy
    variables:
      azureResourceGroup: ''
      kubernetesCluster: ''
      subdomain: ''
    jobs:
    ${{ each filename in /myfolder/*.yaml}}:
       valueFile: $filename 
       - template: Templates/deploy-helmchart.yaml@pipelinetemplates
```

deploy-helmchart.yaml

```
 jobs:
    - job: Deploy
      pool:
        vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
      steps:
      - task: HelmInstaller@1
        displayName: 'Installing Helm'
        inputs:
          helmVersionToInstall: '2.15.1'
        condition: and(succeeded(), startsWith(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/v'))  

      - task: HelmDeploy@0
        displayName: 'Initializing Helm'
        inputs:
          connectionType: 'Azure Resource Manager'
          azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
          azureResourceGroup: $(azureResourceGroup)
          kubernetesCluster: $(kubernetesCluster)
          command: 'init'
        condition: and(succeeded(), startsWith(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/v'))  

      - task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: 'Fetching GitTag'
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            # Write your PowerShell commands here.
            Write-Host "Fetching the latest GitTag"
            $gt = git describe --abbrev=0
            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=gittag]$gt"
        condition: and(succeeded(), startsWith(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/v'))    


      - task: Bash@3
        displayName: 'Fetching repo-tag'
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            echo GitTag=$(gittag)
            echo BuildID=$(Build.BuildId)
            echo SourceBranchName=$(Build.SourceBranchName)
            echo ClusterName= $(kubernetesCluster)

      - task: HelmDeploy@0
        displayName: 'Upgrading helmchart'
        inputs:
          connectionType: 'Azure Resource Manager'
          azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
          azureResourceGroup: $(azureResourceGroup)
          kubernetesCluster: $(kubernetesCluster)
          command: 'upgrade'
          chartType: 'FilePath'
          chartPath: $(chartPath)
          install: true
          releaseName: $(releaseName)
          valueFile: $(valueFile)
          arguments: '--set image.tag=$(gittag) --set subdomain=$(subdomain)'
        condition: and(succeeded(), startsWith(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/tags/v'))
```

Another thing is that if the jobs can get access to the GitHub repo by default or do I need to do something in the job level?

Besides how can I use for-loop in the job for this case?

Any help would be appreciated.

Updated after getting comments from @Leo

Here is a PowerShell task that I added in deploy-helmchart.yaml for fetching the files from a folder in GitHub.

```
 - task: PowerShell@2
   displayName: 'Fetching Files'
   inputs:
     targetType: 'inline'
     script: |
       Write-Host "Fetching values files"
       cd myfolder
       $a=git ls-files
       foreach ($i in $a) {
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=filename]$i"
          Write-Host "printing"$i
       }
```

Now the question is how can I run the task: HelmDeploy@0 for each files using parameters?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> if the jobs can get access to the GitHub repo by default or do I need to do something in the job level?

The answer is yes.

We could add a command line task in the jobs, like `job1` to clone the GitHub repository by Github PAT, then we could access those files (`value-f1.yaml`, `values-f2.yaml`,...) in `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`:

```
git clone https://<GithubPAT>@github.com/XXXXX/TestProject.git
```

> Besides how can I use for-loop in the job for this case?

You could create a template which will have a set of actions, and pass parameters across during your build, like:

deploy-helmchart.yaml:

```
parameters:
  param : []

steps:
  - ${{each filename in parameters.param}}:
    - scripts: 'echo ${{ filename  }}'
```

pipeline.yaml:

```
steps:
 - template: deploy-helmchart.yaml
   parameters:
     param: ["filaname1","filaname2","filaname3"]
```

Check the document [Solving the looping problem in Azure DevOps Pipelines](https://mattvsts.github.io/2019/05/04/solving-the-looping-problem-in-Azure-DevOps-Pipelines/) for some more details.

Command line get the latest file name in the foler:

```
   FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\*.txt*" /B /O:D') DO SET NewestFile=%%I
    
   echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=NewFileName]NewestFile"
```

**Update:**

> Now the question is how can I run the task: HelmDeploy@0 for each
> files using parameters?

It`s depends on whether your` HelmDeploy` task has options to accept the filename parameter.

As I said before, we could use following yaml to invoke the template yaml with parameters:

```
 - template: deploy-helmchart.yaml
   parameters:
     param: ["filaname1","filaname2","filaname3"]
```

But, if the task `HelmDeploy` has no options to accept parameters, we could not run the task `HelmDeploy@0` for each files using parameters.

Then I check the `HelmDeploy@0`, I found there is only one option that can accept **Helm command** parameters:

[image]

So, the answer for this question is **depends on whether your file name can be used as a Helm command**, if not, you could not run the task `HelmDeploy@0` for each files using parameters. If yes, you can do it.

Please check the official document [Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful reply, but I would also like to get the parameters automatically, how can that be done? it's like whenever I push a file in a folder in GitHub, the pipeline gets triggered and run the helmchart deployment (perform the template) using that new file without I add the filename manually in the parameters section.

Comment: @Matrix, That should be a another question, you could add a powershell scripts to get the file name, like [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26656461/using-powershell-to-get-a-file-name-in-a-directory), then set this file name into the ENV value by https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md, then we could get it in the parameters, but how to get the file name you pushed that should be a scripts question, for example, using github API. But that should be not related to Azure devops, which I could not give you much more support.

Comment: @Matrix, So, as I suggest, you could open a new ticket about how to get the file name you pushed to the github with Powershell or command line scripts. I think there are many more professional people willing to help you

Comment: @Matrix, I have created a batch command line to get the latest file name in the folder, you could check my updated answer for some more details. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Matrix, Sorry late reply. I just returned to my office two hours ago, I have updated my answer, you could check the **updated** answer for some more details. Have a nice day :).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204597/discussion-between-matrix-and-leo-liu-msft).

Comment: Do not forget add the colon at the end of the each loop 
`- ${{each filename in parameters.param}}:`