# Can we add screenshots as an attachment to the test result in Azure pipeline

Tags: node.js, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cypress

I am using JUnit for reporting test case results. As per my understanding, we can't attach screenshots or videos as an attachment for the results generated by the 'Publish Test Result' task from a JUnit format in the Azure pipeline.

Below is the code I used for generating screenshots and videos as artifacts rather than attaching to the test results report.

```
   jobs:
- job: Cypress_e2e_tests
  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  variables:
     npm_config_cache: C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\npm-cache  


  steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '10.x'
    - task: CacheBeta@1
      inputs:
        key: npm | $(Agent.OS) | package-lock.json
        path: $(npm_config_cache)
        restoreKeys: npm | $(Agent.OS) | package-lock.json
      displayName: Cache NPM packages  

- task: CacheBeta@1
  inputs:
    key: 'cypress | $(Agent.OS) | package-lock.json'
    path: 'C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Cypress'
    restoreKeys: 'cypress | $(Agent.OS) | package-lock.json'
  displayName: Cache cypress binary

- script: npm cache verify
  displayName: 'NPM verify'

- script: npm ci
  displayName: 'Install NPM dependencies'

- script: npm run cy:verify
  displayName: 'Cypress verify'

- script: |
    npx cypress run --browser chrome
  displayName: 'Run Cypress tests' 
  workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)


- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@0
  displayName: 'Publish Screenshots (Cypress)'
  condition: failed()
  inputs:
      artifactName: 'screenshots'
      targetPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/cypress/screenshots'

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@0
  displayName: 'Publish Videos (Cypress)'
  condition: failed()
  inputs:
      artifactName: 'videos'
      targetPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/cypress/videos'


- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
    testResultsFiles: '*.xml'
    failTaskOnFailedTests: true
    testRunTitle: 'Cypress Test Results'
    publishRunAttachments: true
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

Is there any way to attach these artifacts to the test results rather than keeping those two as separate sections?

If we can generate test results with attachments from a node project (we can attach files using the reporters available for .Net project, but my working project is purely based on the node), it would be the best solution for me.

Comment: I am using cypress for UI testing and please see the reporters supported by cypress https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/reporters.html#Reporter-Options

Answer (score 2):

> Can we add screenshots as an attachment to the test result in azure
>   pipeline

For this issue, the answer is **yes**. You can write a script in PowerShell task and call  [Create Test Result Attachment](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/rest/api/azure/devops/test/attachments/create%20test%20result%20attachment?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#response) rest api in it . Through this rest api, you can attach a file to a test result.

Request url :

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/Results/{testCaseResultId}/attachments?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

Sample request body:

```
{
  "stream": "VXNlciB0ZXh0IGNvbnRlbnQgdG8gdXBsb2FkLg==",
  "fileName": "Notifications.png",
  "comment": "Test attachment upload",
  "attachmentType": "GeneralAttachment"
}
```

Below is my test in postman :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, I think this might help me to upload attachments. But I am not sure about I can automate the above process, in the sense, I have set of tests and the cypress will create screenshots for each test run on failure and the file name for the screenshot should be the same as the filename of the test. How can I iterate through each test run results and attach the corresponding file to the result?

Comment: According to your yaml script, you publish the screenshot to the `s / cypress / screenshots` folder, then you can traverse the test results through [Results-List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1), then get the latest file name from the `screenshots` folder(you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59387555/using-for-loop-in-azure-pipeline-jobs/59402989#59402989)), and then add the file as attachment.

Comment: Hi   Hugh Lin - MSFT, Do we have any other options/features available in cypress/azure to attach files to test results as looping through each test and calling API will make more overhead if we have a bulk amount of test cases.

Comment: AFAIK, except using the rest api, it can only be added manually through the UI.