# Azure DevOps Test Report Embed Attachments/Screenshots

Tags: azure-devops

When I download the Azure DevOps Test Report for a certain Test Plan, I want anyone with the PDF to be able to look at the screenshot links provided in the report. Right now, the screenshot links lead me to sign into Azure.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpjmf.jpg
For example, in the picture, I want anyone with the PDF to be able to view screenshot.png without having to log in. Is there anyway to embed/include the screenshots into the report for anyone to see? Right now when downloading the test report there is no feature that includes this.

Thanks!

Comment: There is also this other solution: [Other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59511868/can-we-add-screenshots-as-an-attachment-to-the-test-result-in-azure-pipeline)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there anyway to embed/include the screenshots into the report for
> anyone to see?

I afraid there is such out of box way to show the screenshot in azure report currently. And azure devops does not support publishing generic HTML in build/release pipeline.

Test result you saw may under the **Tests** tab of the azure pipeline build result page. And it is the xml format report which has been published to azure devops, not the html report which contains the screenshots.

There is [feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/491426/support-for-generic-html-publishing-inside-build-a.html) regarding this issue which has been submitted to Microsoft develop team. You can go vote on it or create one of your own.

As a workaround, you can use the [publish build artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) to publish the screenshots as artifacts of the pipeline.

```
steps:
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: TestScreenshots'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(System.defaultworkingdirectory)/target/home-page-html' #path to the test result folder(ie. html:target/home-page-html)
    ArtifactName: TestScreenshots
```

Then you can get the screenshots from the build **Summary** page, See below:

If the screenshots reside in multiple test result folders. You can use [copy files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to copy the screenshots to a place and then publish to build artifacts.

[image]