# Azure yaml pipeline using "extends"

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, yaml, continuous-deployment

I am trying to use extends as part of my pipeline. I am trying to get the first basic step working from Azure docs ie

```
    # pythonparameter-template.yml
    parameters:
    - name: usersteps
      type: stepList
      default: []
    steps:
    - ${{ each step in parameters.usersteps }}
      - ${{ step }}

# azure-pipelines.yml
trigger: none

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: CI-CD-Templates
    type: git
    name: /CI-CD-Templates
    ref: refs/heads/master

extends:
  template: /pythonparameter-template.yml@CI-CD-Templates
  parameters:
    usersteps:
    - script: echo This is my first step
    - script: echo This is my second step
```

I keep getting the below error:

> The directive 'each' is not allowed in this context. Directives are not supported for expressions that are embedded within a string. Directives are only supported when the entire value is an expression
>   Unexpected value '${{ each step in parameters.usersteps }} - ${{ step }}'

Also after I extend from a template can azure-pipelines.yml also have it's own custom steps ie

```
# azure-pipelines.yml
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: templates
    type: git
    name: MyProject/MyTemplates
    ref: tags/v1

extends:
  template: template.yml@templates
  parameters:
    usersteps:
    - script: echo This is my first step
    - script: echo This is my second step
steps:
- template: /validation-template.yml@CI-CD-Templates
 parameters:
  commitMessage: $(commitMessage)

- template: /shared-template.yml@CI-CD-Templates
 parameters:
 buildArtifactDir: $(buildArtifactDir)
```

Comment: I have seen, that there is a typo in your script. 
`- ${{ each step in parameters.usersteps }}:
      - ${{ step }}`

you are missing : at the end of first line

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Please refer the response in this DC link-- [Yaml extends feature erroring out when looping through steps.](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1080415/yaml-extends-feature-erroring-out-when-looping-thr.html?childToView=1081479#comment-1081479)

​The YAML has a validation task in #pythonparameter-template.yml
Comment out these 2 lines and your YAML will succeed. The template shown here is preventing any tasks to be used. This could be a scenario for someone with specific security requirements.

```
  ${{ if eq(pair.key, 'task') }}:
    '${{ pair.value }}': error
```

---

Are you trying to combine two yml `pythonparameter-template.yml` `azure-pipelines.yml` in the same file? It's not supported.

```
    parameters:
    - name: usersteps
      type: stepList
      default: []
    steps:
    - ${{ each step in parameters.usersteps }}
      - ${{ step }}
```

According to the error `Directives are not supported for expressions that are embedded within a string. Directives are only supported when the entire value is an expression Unexpected value '${{ each step in parameters.usersteps }} - ${{ step }}'`

You maybe use the wrong format. About the formats you could refer our official doc here--
[Template types & usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#extend-from-a-template)

Besides, you can make azure-pipelines.yml also have it's own custom steps. But you need to put them under parameters in the pipeline, not like the way you use.

**azure-pipelines.yml**

```
trigger:
- master

extends:
  template: pythonparameter-template.yml
  parameters:
    buildSteps:  
      - bash: echo Test #Passes
        displayName: succeed
      - bash: echo "Test"
        displayName: succeed
      - script: echo "Script Test" 
        displayName: Fail
```

Comment: No I am not combining the two yml file. The pythonparameter-template.yml is in a separate repo.

Comment: Using the link you sent (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#extend-from-a-template) when I try to extend start.yml I get an error as, Unexpected value 'CmdLine@2' but atleast the foreach iteration is happening.
When I try to escape the @ symbol as CmdLine\@2 the validation passes but the if condition ${{ if ne(pair.value, 'CmdLine@2') }} is not satisfied. So I am not sure if the escape is working as well.

Comment: Hi BP_QA, no need to use \ here, this should be a document issue. It's just a sample how to use for each iteration  and extend.  You could also only use each expression, but you are using the wrong format.  Detail usage of each, you could refer this blog: https://mattvsts.github.io/2019/05/04/solving-the-looping-problem-in-Azure-DevOps-Pipelines/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59387555/using-for-loop-in-azure-pipeline-jobs . Hope this helps.

Comment: The issue is not with looping, I am easily able to iterate through all the steps in the azure-pipeline.yml as below.
But the issue is when we want to skip a key like below
- ${{ each step in parameters.buildSteps }}:
      - ${{ each pair in step }}:
          ${{ if ne(pair.value, 'CmdLine@2') }}:
            ${{ pair.key }}: ${{ pair.value }}       
          ${{ if eq(pair.value, 'CmdLine@2') }}: 
            '${{ pair.value }}': error  
OR
If I like to skip a step based on its key say if it is a script ie key = script.

Comment: I have raised a Microsoft Developer community ticket for this and they have acknowledged that they are able to reprouce the issue. The ticket is
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1080415/yaml-extends-feature-erroring-out-when-looping-thr.html?childToView=1081479#comment-1081479

Comment: Hi @BP_QA According to  the  response from above DC link. The YAML has a validation task in #pythonparameter-template.yml
Comment out these 2 lines and your YAML will succeed. The template shown here is preventing any tasks to be used. This could be a scenario for someone with specific security requirements.
      `${{ if eq(pair.key, 'task') }}:
        '${{ pair.value }}': error` You need to comment that two lines to make it work.