# Is it possible to create a step for each file in directory in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure-pipelines

Basically what I need is the following: In the repository I'm building, there's in some agreed-upon directory a bunch of `*_test.m` files. I want to run each of these MATLAB files separately, optimally in a step of its own so it is very clear to the user where it failed.

In the answer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59387555/using-for-loop-in-azure-pipeline-jobs), the following example is given:

```
# template-file.yaml
parameters:
  param : []

steps:
  - ${{each filename in parameters.param}}:
    - scripts: 'echo ${{ filename  }}'


# azure-pipelines.yaml

steps:
 - template: deploy-helmchart.yaml
   parameters:
     param: ["filaname1","filaname2","filaname3"]
```

That's the direction, but I'd like 2 things, in the following order of importance:

1. I need to generate the filenames dynamically, based on what there is in the repo.
2. I don't really need it in a template, the {{ each }} expression is perfectly fine to be in the root azure-pipelines.yaml

Is that possible?